# What if I let morkvarg go, will I encounter him again?

Tags: the-witcher-3

So I am this quest and have killed Morkvarg, but it leaves me curious, what if I had just let him go.

I tried looking around, but all I can find are people who just found him such a scumbag that after gathering the reward they backstabbed him to death.

But now I'm curious, has anyone ever let him roam free? Does he have an effect on npc stories? Will he become a big looting pillaging presence in the game? or does he vanish into nothingness after the quest?

So what happens to Morkvarg if you let him go into the world? Prefably answers from experience of letting Morkvarg roaming free, as the wiki's don't detail about what happens after the quest in the rare case you let him go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing happens, you never meet up with him again.

He doesn't have any effect on other NPC's, except the shop dealer who gives you an additional little bonus.

[This page here](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/In_Wolf%27s_Clothing) tells you everything about [Morkvarg](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Morkvarg) and the quest.

Comment: Is this from experience or just the wiki? because i've read the wiki's about him and they are not satisfactory in answering the question.

Comment: @Tschallacka Yes it's from personal experience. I've saved him on 2 playthroughs where I completed every quest. I included the wiki pages because having those available in answers provides additional information for those seeking it. If you search elsewhere you'll get the same answer that I provided.

Comment: For example, can you just follow him and see where he goes?